# How does the function printf works in C?

Tags: c

I met a problem when I test the function printf:

First I write code like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a = 'a';
    printf("a = %f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

[image]

And then I write code:

```
int main(void)
{
    float b = 'a';
    printf("b = %f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

[image]

And then I write code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a = 'a';
    float b = 'a';
    printf("b = %f\n", b);
    printf("a = %f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

[image]

So I am confused why in the first program `a` = `0.000000` and in the third program `a` = `97.000000`?
How does the function `printf()` work?
How does the symbol `%f`, `%d` work?

Comment: RTFM, e.g. read [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and/or [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: You are confused about printf but `float b = 'a';`  is okay for you? ;)

Comment: @sebastian sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** after doing some more research on this, it seems that the differences between the `float` and `int` memory representations are not the ones responsible for the behaviour of the three programs.

I've looked at the object code for the third program and I found the cause of the odd behaviour: the floating point arguments are sent to other registry/stack than the integer ones. And `printf` relies on that and looks them up in other locations than the ones the callee of `printf` (i.e. the `main` method) places the arguments.

Here's the relevant disassembly of the the third program (for an x86_64 architecture):

```
0000000100000f18    leaq    0x71(%rip), %rdi        ## literal pool for: "b = %f\n"
0000000100000f1f    movsd   0x61(%rip), %xmm0      ## b variable gets sent to xmm0
0000000100000f27    movl    $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100000f2e    movb    $0x61, -0x5(%rbp)      ## a variable gets placed on the callee stack
0000000100000f32    movsd   %xmm0, -0x10(%rbp)
0000000100000f37    movsd   -0x10(%rbp), %xmm0
0000000100000f3c    movb    $0x1, %al
0000000100000f3e    callq   0x100000f66             ## symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000f43    leaq    0x4e(%rip), %rdi        ## literal pool for: "a = %f\n"
0000000100000f4a    movsbl  -0x5(%rbp), %esi
0000000100000f4e    movl    %eax, -0x14(%rbp)
0000000100000f51    movb    $0x0, %al
0000000100000f53    callq   0x100000f66             ## symbol stub for: _printf
```

And `printf` relies on this, it assumes the callee has placed `%f` arguments in the `xmm0`/`xmm1`/etc registers, and the behaviour of the three programs is like this:

1. in the first program `printf` looks for the `%f` argument in the xmm0 register, however as we're at the start of the program, the register is clean and `main` has placed `a` into `eax`, thus `xmm0` holds a zero value, and this is what `printf` prints
2. in the second program `main` correctly places `b` in `xmm0`, and `printf` takes it from there, printing the correct value
3. in the third program due to the fact that `b` is printed first, the `xmm0` register will hold this value, and since `printf` doesn't mess with the register, when it's called the second time it fetches again from `xmm0` that remained intact after the first `printf` call.

So it's all about caller/callee conventions on where integers and floats are being send by the caller and from where the callee tries to pick them up.


**Original response:** In the first program you are trying to print a float, but you pass an int (char is a smaller int). Due to the fact that ints and floats have different binary representations, the int 97 (corresponding to the character 'a') corresponds to a very small float: 1.36E-43, that gets printed as zero.

Here is the binary representation of 97 (the compiler expands any 1-byte char to a 4-byte argument when calling a function)
`00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001`

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is the standard format for binary representations of float/double numbers, you can play with an online converter [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), and you can see how the same binary number has different values when its interpreted as an int or as a float.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can it explain the third program?

Comment: Well, I think this is one of those undefined behaviours you get when you don't match the format string and the list of arguments passed to printf. Be glad that you didn't had a crash :)

Comment: I think it is the output buffer lead to the output in the third program. Because when I exchange the two printf sentences the output came out a = 0.000000 b = 97.000000.

Answer (score 5):

The `%f` here represents a replacement token for a float.

In order to replace a char you'd need `%c`.

[Here is a list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) that tells you what is the appropriate replacement token for each type.

Comment: I do know this. But I want to know when I use %f instead of %c, what will the function printf do ? How does it read the register?

Comment: @Mr.CodeMonkey, what you are doing is undefined behaviour so _anything_ is a valid outcome, up to and including total destruction of the universe. In other words, don't do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

%f is for Float
 %c for characters

```
The 97 which you have got is the ASCII value for 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

As per latest 'C' standard it's an undefined behavior. Check 7.21.6.1 pt 9 of from c standard draft.

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

So when things are said to have undefined behavior anything is possible and behavior may vary from one compiler to another. 'C' let's you cut your toe with an axe but that doesn't me you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

`%f` is for float. You must use `%c` for characters.

If you use

```
    printf("a = %c\n", a);
```

You'll get the character.

So, if you change your first code to

```
int main(void)
{
    char a = 'a';
    printf("a = %c\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

You will get output as

```
a
```

Comment: I know. But I want to know what is the difference between %f and %c ?

Comment: @Mr.CodeMonkey , you might want to check the output I got [here](http://ideone.com/DOVli0)

Comment: Oh, why? I use clodeblocks13.12. My os is windows7 64bit. Do you know why our output is different?

Comment: @Mr.CodeMonkey , the difference in output is probably because of how the compiler interprets it.

Comment: I guess it depends on the data in uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between

```
printf("%f\n, 97.0);
```

and

```
printf("%c\n, 'a');
```

is that the *printf* function reads its parameters from the stack based on the `%X` you give, and interprets them (for display) as such.

For `%c` printf expects a char as parameter, so it will read a char (a byte, but often actually a int, it's implementation dependant) and displays it (it displays the less significant byte if an *int* is provided).

For `%f` printf expects a float (which size in bytes is `sizeof(float)`, usually 4 bytes on gcc / Intel processors).

If you compile with *gcc* use the `-Wall` option that would give a warning when the `%X` format and the type of the parameter do not match.

Comment: I understand what you said. But it can't explain my programme. When I define like char a = 'a'; and printf("a = %f\n", a);Does printf read 4 bytes data starting from the address of a ? If so, the output can't be 0, can it?

Comment: Read the excellent answer from Cristik (above I guess) that explains why you get `0` in that case.