# Value of variable as integer and as double

Tags: c++, c, integer, double

So I have an unsigned integer Q with the value of 0xfccd11c0.

When I print it with `printf("%i", Q);` I get -53669440 which is the signed integer representation of 0xfccd11c0 so I get it.

But when I print it with `printf("%i", (double)Q);` I get 939524096. I DO know that in order to print a double value you need to use `%f` as the string format, but still, what happens when converting to double that is causing that value to be printed?

Comment: It's just printing the integer value of the first 32 bits of the floating-point representation of 4241297856.0 .

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker or, likely on modern machines, printing whatever was last stored in an integer register (which won't be `(double)Q`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Pass-in-register optimized calling conventions generally get disabled when the compiler sees a varargs prototype.

Comment: @BenVoigt http://goo.gl/UCbA1x

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I hate to see the code for the varargs implementation, or is there some indexed addressing for xmm registers and I just don't know it?

Comment: @BenVoigt IDK the details but it's clearly passing the argument via `%xmm0` . Perhaps the compiler has a special case for printf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q is 4241297856

(double)Q has 64-bit IEEE-754 representation 0x41EF99A238000000

In little-endian, the lower 4 bytes of this occupy the same space as (int)Q would.

0x38000000 is 939524096

---

Handy online converter: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs341/IEEE-754.html

Answer (score 4):

Using wrong format specifier in function such as `printf` triggers undefined behaviour; in which case anything could happen.

Comment: It feels like there's something more.. Why does this behavior repeat itself on several machines? It sounds more like looking at a double as an integer is causing some conversion that is changing the value somehow.

Comment: @YonatanNir: In case of UB output can be anything. Btw you triggered UB in your code at two places, also when printing unsigned int with %i; someone else could add other explanations

Comment: @YonatanNir Were you using the same compiler on all of those machines?  It could be that the compiler makes an assumption of how to handle this UB

Comment: It sounds like Ben Voigt gave the more logical answer

Comment: @Yonatan Nir: could be but this had to be mentioned IMO

Answer (score 1):

Here, Q is explicitly converted (by you) to a new memory object, let's call it `Q_dbl`. It's passed to the `printf` function, but as you specified `%i` parameter, this chunk of memory is interpreted as an integer. That's an idea of what happens at low level.

```
unsigned int Q = 0xfccd11c0;

printf("%i", Q);
printf("%i", (double)Q);

auto Q_dbl = (double)Q;

printf("%f", Q_dbl);
printf("%i", Q_dbl);
```

Code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy simulate what happens with this code:

```
unsigned int Q = 0xfccd11c0;
double dQ = (double)Q;
int *x = (int*)(&dQ);
```

*x now is equal to 939524096.

Comment: note that this causes undefined behaviour so may or may not print any particular result.

Comment: Why would this be undefined? You take an address pointer and slap it onto another type. The memory remains unchanged. Everything is strictly deterministic.

Comment: @RedOctober: Because `&dQ` is not what is passed as an argument to `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see an answer of mine to a similar question: [How does the function printf works in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665599/how-does-the-function-printf-works-in-c/29665747#29665747). Basically the C compiler executes integer and floating-point operations on two different sets of registries, and `printf` extracts it's arguments from the registries corresponding to the format string. This is one of the reasons that causes `printf`'s weird behaviours when the format string and the passed arguments don't match.

Note that this happens for a reduced number of arguments, when the compiler optimisations place the arguments in the available registries instead of placing them on the stack.